# Domain filter does not work in odoo xml file

Tags: xml, odoo

What I want to do is, I need to filter customer/partner based on their pincodes.
So, I created a boolean field called `is_pincode_present` and a `compute` function to calculate its value. But it doesn't return filtered values; instead, it returns all customers.

I tried using Xpath to hide the values, but it didn't work. Xpath only hid the fields, instead of doing the filtering.

This is my `py.file`:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):

        _inherit = "res.partner"

        is_pincode_present = fields.Boolean('zip', compute="_is_pincodes_present")

        def _is_pincodes_present(self):
                pin_lists = self.env['franchise.pincode.master'].search([('name','=',self.env.user.partner_id.id)],limit=1).mapped("franchise_pincode_line.pincode.pincode") //list of pincodes 
                for i in self:
                     if i.zip in pin_lists:
                        i.is_pincode_present = True
```

This is my XML file, following xml file inherited from res.partner tree view:

```
        <record id="action_view_partner_form_one" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Customers/Suppliers</field>
            <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,pivot</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_partner_tree"/>
            **<field name="domain">[('is_pincode_present','=',1)]</field>** // domain
            <field name="help" type="html">
                  <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                  </p>
                </field>
        </record>
```

quick fixes help me to complete tasks. `is_pincode_present` is setting correct values in the database, it is working fine when other filters are applied. Only boolean filters don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Baskar

To apply the search domain on the `compute` field you have to make them `store=True` which will store the value in the database. And with this change, your filter is applied.

```
is_pincode_present = fields.Boolean('zip', compute="_is_pincodes_present", store=True)
```

Comment: i applied store=True but doesn't worked @Dipen Shah any other solutions pls

Comment: make sure your method is triggering, You need to define the depends on the compute method. Once that field is altering your method is a trigger and it will store the value in the Database.

Comment: i checked it triggering every recode but domain filter 0nly not appied

Comment: 'is_pincode_present' this field is added in view?

Comment: yes, all filters working but only this field domain not working

Comment: Did you check that is your field 'is_pincode_present' is computing with true? take one record to check and trace if your method is invoked then it is making this filed true? Also, put visibility on view to ease.